# How to remove all associated data of the removed object in SequelizeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var MenuTranslation = sequelize.define('MenuTranslation', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.STRING
},{
    tableName: 'menu_translations',
    timestamps: false,
    associate: function(models){ 
      MenuTranslation.belongsTo(models.Menu, { onDelete: 'cascade' });
      MenuTranslation.belongsTo(models.Language);
    }
});

return MenuTranslation;
};
```

UPDATE: I add "onDelete: 'cascade'" into my MenuTranslation model. But this time it worked like onDelete: 'null'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onDelete` option goes on the child object, not on the parent. It's as in SQL. [Relevant documentation](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/#foreign-keys).

Comment: You are right, but this time cascade didn't work. Please check update